# software for creating dynamic list of things?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I want create a list of product with their name and price . Like a table at database.

```
example :

  id    name    price    date 
|      |      |        |      |
|      |      |        |      |
|      |      |        |      |
|      |      |        |      |
|      |      |        |      |
|      |      |        |      |
```

Can you recommend me a software, which is available at 12.04 ?

Comment: Why don't you use `Libre Calc` or `Base`. Which format you want to create it? is it in document/excel sheet or database file. How you will get the data? is manually added? Please give details of the complete workflow

Comment: Purpose is storing information on database.

Comment: Then create a database file in `Base` (equivalent to Microsoft access). Add a table, and add the columns you required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Web-E told you, if you will insert the data manually, you should use LibreOffice Calc or Base.
I always use Calc for these purposes.